# Control wifi document scanner in an android app

Tags: android, printing, wifi, integration, image-scanner

I am looking for a way to control a wifi document scanner through an android application (that scans PDF files). The scanner model has not yet been chosen. It may also be an all-in-one printer.

I know that HP has an [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hp.printercontrol) that allows control of their all in one printers but I am looking for a way to integrate these functionalities to a custom app.

More specifically, these are the points for which I need light (that correspond to the approaches I have thought about):

1. Is there a standard protocol for communication with a wifi scanner (like IPP for printers)?
2. Is there a way to interact with an other app from which I don't have much documentation (send an intent or whatever)?
3. Is there a known alternative to a wi-fi scanner (like the [Google Cloud Print](http://www.google.ca/cloudprint/learn/))?

Thanks in advance for any hint that could help me in my search.

Answer (score 0):

There is a library that can help. The http://roncemer.com/software-development/java-ocr/. Hope it helps.